# Using the current SUMIF "row" in criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to do something like this:
=SUMIF(H2:H55,VLOOKUP(*insert placeholder for current row*,Interfaces_to_Devices,5,FALSE)=A4,J2:J55)

IE I am trying to use the current row that I am evaluating to do a VLOOKUP of a value that needs to be equal to something I specify.

Thank you.

[image]
In this screen shot I did not include the VLOOKUP()="A4". That is supposed to be in there.

Comment: This sounds like a very general task, and a very simple formula should do the trick. But with the info you provided it nearly impossible to figure out what you want. The first argument in `VLOOKUP` is not a row number. But a value to look for in the left most column of your look up range. It looks like you want the current rows value in column 5 of your table named Interfaces_to_Devices. but you are then comparing that value to another making your formula evaluate to sum of `J2:J55` where the value in column H of that row is true or false. Please add more data,or an example for a real answer

Comment: You're right, I wanted the actual value not the row, please see my comment below.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a screen shot of some sample data and a brief explanation of what exactly your want? No pseudo code just an explanation of what you'd like.

Comment: I added a screen shot I hope helps.

Answer (score 1):

`ROW()` will return the number of the current row.

But the first argument to VLOOKUP is a cell reference or value.

If you explain what value you are trying to use in the VLOOKUP, how it is related to the current cell, then it is probably possible to use INDEX and MATCH (perhaps OFFSET) to achieve what you need.

Comment: This is getting close I think. SUMIF works by going through each row from the first argument, and seeing if it satisfies the criteria. If it does then it adds the corresponding value from the last argument to the sum, right? I want to use the current value that is being used in the criteria, in VLOOKUP as a part of the criteria. This is why I asked the question because it is so damn confusing to say that I can't guess how to even ask it. IE. A typical SUMIF(range,"range(i)<100",sum_range). I want to do this: SUMIF(range,"VLOOKUP(range(i), lookup table, 5, FALSE)=something",sum_range).

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIF(H2:H55,VLOOKUP(ROW(),Interfaces_to_Devices,5,FALSE)=A4,J2:J55)
```

Or

```
=SUMIF(H2:H55,INDEX(Interfaces_to_Devices,5,ROW())=A4,J2:J55)
```

If you simply REFERENCE the first value in column 5 of  Interfaces_to_Devices, then drag down your formula you will simply reference each value going down the column without the need for a lookup, index, or match.

Notice in the picture below how i replace your formula with the cell reference to the 5th column in the table and in my first Row i Reference the first value in the column then as i drag the formula down it automatically references the equivalent cells in each row down the column.

[image]